# Which engine is better ?

Tags: engine, power

So i have two engines on my storage to use on my mini "cub" bike the one is 110cc with 6,7 hp and the other one is 100cc but with 7,5 hp so which is the faster the one that has more cc but with less hp or the other which has lower cc but more hp ?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You should qualify what you mean by "faster" here. Are you referring to acceleration or top speed. And is the max RPM the same for both engines? If not, what are they?

Comment: A major consideration here is weight. One might have more HP and torque but be heavier.

Comment: Both max RPM are 8000rpm  the one 110cc is a lifan and the other one is honda 100 engine those are for motorbike's or we call them on our country ''cub's'' like the honda super cub and yes im regarding to top speed cause the top speed i've done on my 110cc engine is 95 km/h the other one engine i don't have tested it yet.

Answer (score 1):

More HP does equal more speed *potential*.

Torque is a greater factor in acceleration in most cases.

Ultimately, the displacement (cc measurement) doesn’t determine speed at all.

If you have the same gearbox for both motors, the higher HP (100cc) motor will provide better *potential* speeds (assuming that the torque is also higher). However, your gearbox may become the limiting factor if the motor is strong enough to peg the las gear with usual load.